# operator IN works in OR mode need IN logic with AND mode

Tags: mysql

Consider this table 'cat_post':

```
entry_id    cat_id
2           2
2           4
2           76
3           2
3           4
3           76
4           2
4           76
```

I need to select the entries that have both a row with `cat_id = 2` and one with `cat_id = 4` (not all entries that have either 2 or 4), so this select:

```
select * from cat_post where cat_id IN (2,4)
```

will produce:

```
entry_id    cat_id
2           2
2           4
3           2
3           4
4           2
```

Which is not what I want. I need to get entries if they have both a row with 2 and one with 4, but not 2 or 4, like:

```
entry_id    cat_id
2           2
2           4
3           2
3           4
```

(without entry_id 4 in this case)

What query can I use to get this result?

Comment: @Ravi: how to improve that rate?

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy go to your profile, questions tab, then accept ans for question u asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
select entry_id from cat_post where cat_id in (2,4)
  group by entry_id
  having count(*) = 2;
```

This is extensible to more than two values in your "in" set, but will fail if `(entry_id,cat_id)` is not a unique key. If that's not the case, use:

```
select entry_id from cat_post where cat_id in (2,4)
  group by entry_id
  having count(distinct cat_id) = 2;
```

Example:

```
mysql> select * from t;
+------+------+
| e    | c    |
+------+------+
|    2 |    2 |
|    2 |    4 |
|    3 |    2 |
|    3 |    4 |
|    4 |    2 |
|    5 |    4 |
+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select e from t where c in (2,4) group by e having count(*) = 2;
+------+
| e    |
+------+
|    2 |
|    3 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: +1 but I'd change `count(*) = 2` to `count(distinct cat_id) = 2` if pair `entry_id` and `cat_id` isn't unique.

Comment: Works For Me, just added an example. Are you sure you got the group by right, @OleksandrKhavdiy?

Comment: @Mat: ah, need 2-2,2-4,3-2,3-4

Comment: @MichałPowaga: yes, that could very well be a problem, I had assumed the uniqueness - fixed.

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy: I don't understand your comment. Maybe the version suggested bu Michał works better for you?

Comment: @Mat: sorry, your results are 2,3. But I need advanced, like 2-2,2-4,3-2,3-4 (entry_id-cat_id)

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy: you _know_ all the entry ids have the corresponding category ids. Why do you need those spelled out? Would you also need for example `2-8` if entry_id had categories 2, 4 and 8?

Answer (score 2):

Your column cannot be 2 values at the same time. (unless there's a new relativity theory)

Comment: I think you're missing the point, the examples are pretty clear about what the tables contain and what is being seeked.

Comment: @Kurt Du Bois: Benoit and Mat have researched it :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

```
SELECT *
  from cat_post cp
 where cat_id IN (2,4)
   AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM cat_post
                WHERE entry_id = cp.entry_id
                  AND cat_id = 6 - cp.cat_id
              )
```

Comment: @Oleksandr Khavdiy: 6-4=2, 6-2=4.

Comment: ha ha, that indeed works, you are genius :), only what if i pass(2,4,45,678) ?

Comment: @Oleksandr Khavdiy: `AND EXISTS (... and cat_id = 2) AND EXISTS (... and cat_id = 4) AND EXISTS (... and cat_id = 45) AND EXISTS(... and cat_id = 78)` etc.

Comment: this is also solution and works great just Mat solution is more sutable in my case!!! Many Thanks!!!